# How long to regrow hair?

Tags: growth, hair

This is one of the questions I wasn't exactly sure where to post. Basically, I want to make an X-Men parody, and for the part of Professor X I need to shave off my hair. Now I have a simple french crop, not really long or anything, but I was wondering if there's an estimate for how long it would take me to regrow my hair. Again, sorry if this is the wrong site, but I just thought "human body", so I guess it fits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_hair_growth:

> Scalp hair is known to grow **between 0.6cm and 3.36cm per month**. The growth rate of scalp hair somewhat depends on age (hair tends to grow more slowly with age), sex, and ethnicity. It was previously thought that Caucasian hair grew more quickly than Asian hair and that the growth rate of women's hair was faster than that of men.
>
> However, more recent research has shown that the growth rate of hair in men and women does not significantly differ and that the hair of Chinese people grew more quickly than the hair of French Caucasians and West and Central Africans.

Depending on your age, follicle-condition, nutrition or possible inhibiting factors it can vary how long it will take until your hair has grown back to the previous length.

Comment: With that in mind, I should be back to full lenght in 1-2 months. That's doable, thank you.

Comment: @MatNX Pleasure (gern geschehen), if you take the average (1.98 cm/month) and estimate a french crop with about 4 cm, it should take about two month ;)